# Concatenating multiple strings in call transcripts

Tags: r

I've got a data set that looks like a thousand rows of the following:

```
dat = c("Speaker 1: ONE TWO THREE | Speaker 2: FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN | Speaker 1: EIGHT NINE TEN | Speaker 2: ELEVEN* TWELVE THIRTEEN | Speaker 1: FOURTEEN FIFTEEN","Speaker 1: ONE TWO")
```

```r
dat = tolower(dat) #lowercase 
dat = gsub("\\*","",dat) #strip asterisks
```

I'm trying to get it to look like the following:

```
dat[1]:
Four five six seven. Eleven twelve thirteen.
dat[2]:
NA #(or blank)
```

That is, I want to remove anything from Speaker 1, remove asterisks, change what remains to sentence case, and put a period at the end of each statement.

Any assistance is appreciated, especially if this solution exists here and I failed to find it.

Answer (score 1):

using base R you could do:

```
a = gsub(".*?2:\\s*([^|]*)\\b|(?:(?!Speaker 2).)*","\\L\\1. ", dat, perl = T)
b = gsub("\\*", "", sub("(?|(?<=^)|(?<=\\W))\\W*$", '', a, perl = T))
`is.na<-`(b,nchar(b)==0)


[1] "four five six seven. eleven twelve thirteen."
[2] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to apply many operations on the same object and you need the `str_trim` function its best to use `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat = tolower(dat) #lowercase 
dat = gsub("\\*","",dat) #strip asterisks
res2 <- strsplit(dat, "\\|") %>%
        lapply(function(elt) str_trim(elt[!grepl("speaker 1", elt)])) %>%
        lapply(gsub, pattern = "speaker +[[:digit:]] *: *", replacement ="") %>%
        lapply(function(elt) if (length(elt)) paste0(elt, ".")) %>% 
        lapply(str_trim) %>% 
        lapply(paste0, collapse = " ") # split every string in the vector on 
        # the occurrences of "|" and make transformations
res2[nchar(res2) == 0] <- NA_character_ # set empty strings NA
resvec <- unlist(res2) #turn the result into a vector again
```

```
resvec
[1] "four five six seven. eleven twelve thirteen." NA
```